# fedora17 svn 1.7.5 entries only has a number 12

Tags: svn, fedora

use svn version 1.7.5 check out a project.
I find only at the top directory has a .svn subdirectory. And there is no .svn at others subdirectory.

I also find that there is only one number 12 at the .svn/entries file. There is no url or other information.

when I run svn update , the information is "Updating '.' ".
SO ,how can I find the url?
Is there something error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Subversion 1.7, the ubiquitous `.svn` folders have been banished from all directories except for the *root* directory. These have always been *don't look* directories. They were suppose to be filled with magic and contained [no user serviceable parts](http://blog.makezine.com/2005/08/23/no-user-serviceable-parts/).

We eventually figured out what it contained and its format, and many people use to poke and prod to figure out the information they wanted. All that's gone with Subversion 1.7.

Subversion has a whole slew of commands that can give you exactly the information you need. The `svn info` command will tell you the revision you're on, the most current revision, who made the last change, the root URL, the current working directory, etc. Pretty much everything you're asking. The `--xml` flag even outputs this information in XML which makes it easy for scripts to parse.

To get a listing of all Subversion commands, use `svn help`. Everything you need to know is available via these commands.

Answer (score 0):

```
svn info
```

Will give repository URL,revision, and last change time